Error occurred prior to updating JUnit 4 to JUnit 5
Before the update, don't run my class RunTest, get a error in execution
package automation;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json",       "br.com.dimensa.hooks.TestEventHandlerPlugin" }, features = { "src/test/resources/features" }, glue  = { "br.com.dimensa.hooks", "utils", "automation.steps" }, tags = "@Amplis")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)
public class RunTest {
}

Attempting to update this, but encountering an error. I get this error below:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeTags;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
@Suite
@Cucumber
@SelectClasspathResource("src/test/resources/features")
@IncludeTags("WIP")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty, json:target/cucumber-json-    report.json, core.hooks.TestEventHandlerPlugin")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.MethodName.class)
public class RunTest {
}

This is Error Log:
jun. 18, 2024 4:27:45 PM io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.FeatureResolver resolvePackageResourceWarnIfNone
WARNING: No features found in package 'automation'


At a glance I can see some problems. I think it would be best to start over and make sure you understand what each element does.
Have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton for a minimal working example.
Your problems:

The @Cucumber annotation is deprecated. This causes Cucumber to look for feature in the package of RunTest which I assume is automation.
So don't use it. You are already using @Suite so that is good.

@SelectClasspathResource should target a valid class path resource. Or be replaced with @SelectPackage and a valid package name. The latter would be the better solution.

Your @IncludeTags("WIP") targets a different tag than the original.

@TestMethodOrder does nothing here. It is an annotation from the Jupiter JUnit Engine. The Cucumber Engine is a different Engine on the JUnit 5 Platform, which is different from the Suite Engine, which is different from the Vintage Engine. The original @FixMethodOrder also didn't do anything.



i updated, but now the Test dont Start.
   @Suite
@SelectClasspathResource("src/test/resources/features")

@IncludeTags("@Amplis")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty,         json:target/cucumber-json-report.json, core.hooks.TestEventHandlerPlugin")
public class RunTest {
}

You didn't change @SelectClasspathResource
